# Change some default settings for Firefox globally

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to modify some of the default settings for Firefox globally?

I know how to change settings for user using `about:config`. But I would like to have my changes globally, so that any newly created account will inherit my changes.

I have noticed the file `/usr/share/iceweasel/browser/defaults/preferences/firefox.js` which looks like this might be the place to change settings globally.

Is this the correct way of doing it, or is there a better way? I want to prevent any unintended consequences.

I am using Firefox (Iceweasel) 24.8.1 on [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can.  Mozilla calls this "[locking preferences](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences)", but I prefer to think of it as "system preferences" (they don't have to be locked).

First, tell Firefox you will be using a system preferences file by creating a text file called `local-settings.js` in `defaults/pref` of your Firefox installation directory with these two lines:

```
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
pref("general.config.filename", "mozilla.cfg");
```

Second, your system preferences file.  Create a text file called `mozilla.cfg` in your  Firefox installation directory.  The first line must begin with double forward slashes, then add your preferences (the same preferences as found in [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config)).  An example:

```
//
pref("browser.startup.homepage", http://www.superuser.com);
pref("browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser", false);
```

You have a few options in how you add the preferences:

- `defaultPref` - set new default value
- `pref` - set pref, but allow changes in current session
- `lockPref`  - lock pref, disallow changes

Comment: This looks like the same as [creating `user.js`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file), but with one extra step. See related: [How do I change Firefox's `about:config` from a shell script?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313483/how-do-i-change-firefoxs-aboutconfig-from-a-shell-script). The user.js thing worked for me.

Comment: I believe `http://www.superuser.com` should be quoted in the example.

Comment: Still works in 2023. Even though the linked site is not Mozilla official and seems to had been updated last time several years ago. P.S. `obscure_value` and `//` still seems necessary. Some prefs can be set directly in `local_settings`, some only in `cfg` (for the former `cfg` overwrites if in both).

Answer (score 3):

From [Customizing Firefox - Default Preference Files](http://mike.kaply.com/2012/03/15/customizing-firefox-default-preference-files/) :

> The default preferences are stored in various files like all.js or
>   firefox.js. It is not recommended that you modify these files directly
>   (and you can't easily, because they are stored in the file
>   omni.jar). You can, however, create your own Javascript files and
>   place them in a location so that Firefox reads them as default
>   preferences. That location is the `defaults/pref` directory in
>   the same location where the Firefox executable is placed. Files in
>   this location will be used for all Firefox users (they are not profile
>   specific).
>
> Adding default preferences is as simple as creating a file with the
>   extension of .js in the defaults/preferences directory and adding
>   lines like:
>
> ```
> pref("browser.rights.3.shown", true);
> ```
>
> It's important that you get the format right based on the preference
>   type. In this case, the preference is a boolean, so we specify true or
>   false without quotes as the value on the right. If it is a string, you
>   put it in quotes. If it is an integer, you put the value without
>   quotes. You can tell the type of the preference by looking at the Type
>   column in about:config.
>
> All you can do with the default preferences file is set the default
>   value of preferences. You cannot lock them and you cannot override
>   user set preferences.

If this procedure is too unwieldy, because of the trouble of finding the right names
for the preferences, one can use the add-on [CCK Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cck/)
which provides an easier wizard-like interface :

> The CCK Wizard can be used to **create an extension** that customizes
>   Firefox. To access it, after installation, select Tools->CCK Wizard.
>
> I created this add-on so that people could deploy Firefox exactly the
>   way they wanted, especially enterprise users and educational
>   institutions.
>
> Mozilla does not do enough to support corporate users, and this was my
>   attempt to remedy that.
>
> It allows the following customizations:
>
> - Add identifier to the user agent string
> - Change the default home page and startup override home page
> - Change the title bar text
> - Change the animated logo
> - Change the web page and tooltip used for the animated logo
> - Add a help menu item that links to a web page
> - Provide sites for which popups and XPInstalls are allowed by default
> - Preinstall browser plug-ins
> - Preinstall search engines
> - Add a folder, bookmarks and live bookmarks to the personal toolbar
> - Add a folder, bookmarks and live bookmarks to the bookmarks folder
> - Set default preferences
> - Lock preferences
> - Add registry keys (Windows only)
> - Add certificates
> - Set default proxy configurations
> - Package other XPIs with your distribution
> - Disable about:config

EDIT: CCK has has become CCK2 and moved to [here](https://mike.kaply.com/cck2/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a file called greprefs.js to the Firefox application directory.  In that file, create preferences in the same format as a standard prefs.js file.

The greprefs.js file contains preferences shared amongst all Mozilla applications.

For more detail, see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences