# Blocking pop ups during the propogation of the click event

Tags: firefox

In Firefox there are settings to prevent pop up blocking. Occasionally pop ups are still happening. It looks like Firefox allows pop ups under certain conditions:

> "Is the pop-up shown after a mouse click or a key press?
>
> Certain events, such as clicking or pressing a key, can spawn pop-ups
>   regardless of if the pop-up blocker is on. This is intentional, so
>   that Firefox doesn't block pop-ups that websites need to work."

I would like to turn this off. As a developer I understand that opening pages resulting from a click event is a way to determine if a pop up is desired but for the safety of our users I would like to turn this off.

Is there an option to block event spawned pop ups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this should be configurable and there is a list of events such as mouse clicks, doubleclicks and form submission  that can be used to trigger pop ups.

For more information [Mozilla: dom.popup_allowed_events](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.popup_allowed_events)

1. Browse to `about:config`
2. Click through the security warning
3. Enter `dom.popup_allowed_events` in the search bar. The item that appears is a space separated list of events that can trigger popups
4. Remove the events you don't want. The event names should be obvious as to what they allow.

Another question on Superuser: [Change some default settings for Firefox globally](https://superuser.com/questions/823530/change-some-default-settings-for-firefox-globally) provides information on how to apply that setting to multiple profiles. It should be as simple as appending the config line you want to the current user config file.

---

Alternatively there is an add-on that I suspect will change this setting for you, but I do not know how to insert an add-on and configure it without user intervention.

[Popup Blocker Ultimate](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/popup-blocker-ultimate/)

Comment: That works. I removed all the events listed. Noteworthy: There is a convenient reset button that restores them. It started working right away and I was able to grant sites the options to allow pop ups. Thank you for options. Good work Mozilla! :)